# Having trouble creating a program that uses recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion, sum, definition

I'm trying to write a program that calculates 1+2+3...+n with recursion. I'm just starting to learn C so I'm pretty bad...
Here's what I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int adder;
adder=1;
int sum(int numba) {
    if (adder==numba) {
        return(sum);
    }
    return(sum+adder);
    ++adder;
}

int main() {
    char line[100];
    int nummba;
    printf("Enter in a number: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%d", nummba);
    printf("The sum of numbers from 1 to %d is %d.", nummba, sum(nummba));
    return(0);

}
```

Obviously doesn't work...
How do I use recursion to solve 1+2+3...n?
Thanks.

Comment: Considering that you have a general statement outside of a function, the code you show won't even build. Perhaps that one of your problems (you have more than that)? If you ask questions about build errors, then include the actual errors you're wondering about in the question, copy-pasted in full and complete as text. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The defining characteristic of a recursive function is that it calls itself.  Your function does not do so.  Consider how you might do without variable `adder`, making use instead of the return value of a recursive call to `sum()`.

Comment: `return(sum);` - you don't have anything named `sum` except the function itself. Please, first write *some* code to calculate the sum, which is compiling and giving the correct result. Them change it to comply with your extra requirements. And let alone C. Can you write down a recursive formula for sum?

Comment: A recursive call is just like any other call to any function, and the syntax is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is no need to use global variables.

Secondly in these statements

```
return(sum);
```

and

```
return(sum+adder);
```

`sum` is a pointer to function. So the expressions of the return statements do not make sense.

Moreover this code snippet

```
int adder;
adder=1;
```

will not even compile because you may not use statements in the file scope. At least you should write

```
int adder = 1;
```

The function can look the following way

```
unsigned long long int sum( unsigned int n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n + sum( n - 1 );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int sum( unsigned int n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n + sum( n - 1 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Enter in a non-negative number: " );

    unsigned int n = 0;

    scanf( "%u", &n );

    printf( "The sum of numbers from 0 to %u is %llu.\n", n, sum( n ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter in a non-negative number: 10
The sum of numbers from 0 to 10 is 55.
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion requires that a function calls itself. You are not doing this, so you do not have a recursive function in the first place. Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return n;
    else
        return n + sum(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    char line[100];

    printf("Enter in a number: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    sscanf(line, "%d", &n);
    printf("The sum of numbers from 1 to %d is %d.\n", n, sum(n));

    return(0);
}
```

If you find recursion a bit difficult for now, you can opt for a less difficult solution using a `while` loop:

```
int sum(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    while (j <= n)
    {
        i += j++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: And a third solution would be `return n * (n+1) / 2;`. If we are discussing options here...

Comment: Yes of course. How did I miss that? :)

Comment: `sizeof(line) - 1` --> `sizeof line`: [`fgets()` reads at most one less than the maximum number of characters specified, leaving room for the `\0` terminator.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2p2) More significantly, `sum()` needs to return something when the base case is not satisfied; maybe you meant something like: `n += sum(n - 1);` --> `return n + sum(n - 1)`. Also, careful with negative numbers in the input....

Comment: @exnihilo good points; edited. As for negative numbers, `unsigned` could be used in place of `int` but that requires to change the conversion specifier from `%d` to `%u`, and since the OP mentioned that he is a beginner, I don't want to overwhelm him by making a lot of changes to the code.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about introducing `unsigned` types, but you could make clear in the input prompt that input should be non-negative ;)

Comment: I'd change the comparison in order to check negative values: `if (n <= 0) return 0; else return n + sum(n - 1);` (or a one-liner: `int sum (int n) { return n > 0 ? n + sum(n - 1) : 0; }`). But I woudn't write a recursive function for this task, in the first place. The original question is not a good example to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum_val=0;

void sum(int numba) 
{
    if(numba>=1)
    {
        sum_val=sum_val+numba;
        sum(numba-1);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int nummba;
    printf("Enter in a number: ");
    scanf(" %d",&nummba);
    sum(nummba);
    printf("The sum of numbers from 1 to %d is %d.", nummba, sum_val);
    return(0);
}
```

Did you compile your code?

Comment: Why is this better? What changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? Code-only answers with no explanation is highly discourage because they tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad. And posting comments in answers (like your question) is also wrong. Please read (or refresh) [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Will take care in future.

Comment: The leading whitespace is not needed in `" %d"` since the `%d` directive automatically discards leading whitespace.

Comment: What is the point of using a file scope variable `sum_val`, instead of returning the resulting sum from the function?